# Can anyone explain me how to add Image using WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I already did this:

```
var uriSource = new Uri(@"/WpfApplication1;component/Untitled.png", UriKind.Relative);
image1.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
```

My namespace is WpfApplication1, my image is at main folder of the project.
It still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
It's already set to Resource. When I debug, it says these erros:
Height = 'image.Source.Height' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
Metadata = '(image.Source).Metadata' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: if image in silverlight application you can try to remove namespace.

Comment: Can you post your XAML for image1?  The error message you are getting and the code you have posted don't seem to match.  Maybe the problem is in the XAML.

Comment: @Stewbob, there is no code at XAML about it. I want to add to a Canvas which are in XAML. To add, I go to code behind and do like this: mainCanvas.add(image)

Comment: Your posted code references 'image1', but your error message references 'image'.  Is that a typo, or does image1 become image in some other code?

Comment: man, I just did this at code behind:
Image image1 = new Image();
and then that code

Comment: Is your application named WpfApplication1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it, it's simple as Silverlight. But it doesn't support png files to do like this.
So this how I did to work. Just changed to a jpg image:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.Width = 50;
image.Height = 50;
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/soccer.jpg", UriKind.Relative));

mainCanvas.Children.Add(image);
```

Comment: It doesn't support loading PNG files?

Comment: WPF has full support for png files.  I only use png files in my applications because of the alpha channel capability.  WPF has no problem with these files.

Comment: dude, don't down my asnwer. I have just tested with png, and jpg. It only works with jpg IN THIS CASE!
I mean, only in this code, the png is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that 'Untitled.png' has its Build Action Property set to 'Resource'.
Click on the file in the Solution Explorer, show the Properties dialog, and change the Build Action property.

```
 Dim bi As New BitmapImage()
 bi.BeginInit()
 bi.UriSource = New Uri("/WpfApplication1;component/Untitled.png", UriKind.Relative)
 bi.EndInit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(r[0].ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

image1.Source = bmi; // location + filename
```

work? Assuming that your XAML is somehow similar to this one:

```
<Image x:Name="image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175" Stretch="Fill" Margin="373.428,8,0,5.059">
    <Image.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup/>
    </Image.BindingGroup>
</Image>
```

I've added an Image control inside my Canvas/Layout. (Just having a wild guess)